# How to bypass the hcaptcha in selenium python code for free?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha, browser-automation, hcaptcha

I`m looking for free stable solution of bypassing captchas (hcaptcha specifically). I am aware of some 2captcha.com-like services and everything, but this does not satisfy me. I am thinking about some solutions using the machine learning or bugs. Appreciate any ideas ;)

I have tried [a solution](https://github.com/avengy/hcaptcha-bypass-discord) that is using (or trying to use) bugs to solve hcaptcha. Mb it does work, but I was not able to fugure out how. Please, help me ;(

Comment: are you using headless or nonheadless?

Comment: I have tried different providers like `anti-captcha.com`, `azcaptcha.com`, `2captcha.com`, `deathbycaptcha.com` and `thedataextractors.com/fast-captcha`. And found `anti-captcha`, `azcaptcha` and `fast-captcha` having better results.